# Add image in GMSPolygon

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there a way I can add an image to GMSPolygon?

I can add an image with GMSGroundOverlay but it's not perfect rectangle that I needed.

Please check attached image, In this image, there is a box with black outline is a polygon and I need to add building/floor image in that box.

You can also see GMSGroundOverlay in attached image with white background. GMSGroundOverlay is basically a large rectangle that contains all point added.

[image: Screenshot with polygon & ground overlay]

Thanks,

Comment: Still looking for google-map API instead of mapbox sdk

Comment: you acheived it?? or still not resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the Mapbox SDK.

https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/image-source/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
GMSMarker *ann = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];

    double latitude = [[dictMeter valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [[dictMeter valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    ann.position = coordinate;


ann.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

    UIImageView *markerImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    markerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 60.0);
    markerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [markerImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ann.infoDict valueForKey:@"zone_mapicon"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinImage"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    ann.iconView = markerImage;
      ann.map = self.mapkitView;
```